# JavaEE: Custom class in a EJB remote interface

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I want to add my class as an argument in the stateless, remote interface. For example:

In my remote interface I have this method

```
void connect(MyClass myClass);
```

But I didn't import MyClass (which is a Java Class library) in my interface, so I got an error. Is there any workaround?

In my SessionRemote class I imported MyClass library. Is there any chance to override that method in SessionRemote without importing MyClass in the interface?

```
@Override
public void connect(MyClass myClass){
   myClass.foo();
}
```

I tried to add MyClass library to the interface, but I got lots of errors.

Comment: You will need an import statement in both the interface and implementing class. Without seeing the interface I cannot guess why you're seeing errors when you add an import statement.

Comment: @tzimnoch When I deploy my project I got error like this
error: package data does not exist ArrayList<data.MyClass> foo();
This is an error from the interface. Added java library with data.MyClass to the RemoteInterface project library.

Comment: If it's compiling fine but you get this error on deployment, the class or jar file containing data.MyClass is not available to the runtime. Check your runtime classpath and verify that the appropriate class or jar file is found somewhere in the classpath.

Comment: Can you update your code with all indications given? Both the remote interface and the implementation.